# Can we Assert Toaster messages to check the Actual vs Expected Message?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Automation Testing – Can we Assert the Toaster text and check if the message is as expected or not?

The toaster stays on for 4 seconds without mouse hover.
With mouse hover, it will stay as long as the mouse hover action on the toaster. I want to specifically check for the toaster message post login.

I wrote the below method in SpecflowHooks.cs

```cs
public string Toast(IWebElement Toast)
{
    string ToastMessageDisplayed = Toast.Text;
    return ToastMessageDisplayed;
}
```

And this would get called from Step Definition cs soon after login

```cs
[When(@"I click on Login Button")]
public void WhenIClickOnLoginButton()
{
     loginpage.ClickLoginButton();
     IWebElement LoginToast =driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-toast-notifications__toast__content"));
     Assert.AreEqual("Login Successful", Toast(LoginToast))
}
```

On debugging, I realized that the LoginToast.Text was coming up blank.

Below is the HTML
[image: HTML]

Answer (score 1):

There is an [`ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(locator, text)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_TextToBePresentInElementLocated.htm) to wait for a certain string to exist in the given element. You could use that in your `WhenIClickOnLoginButton()` method.

```
[When(@"I click on Login Button")]
public void WhenIClickOnLoginButton()
{
    loginpage.ClickLoginButton();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.ClassName("react-toast-notifications__toast__content"), "Login Successful"));
        // You could add an Assert.Pass() here if you want but if you get here, you've already confirmed that the element exists with the expected text.
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        Assert.Fail("After clicking the login button, the toast message did not appear with the expected text.");
    }
}
```

---

A couple other suggestions...

1. Use the page object model. Place your locators at the top of the page class and use them in the methods, e.g.

   ```
   public class LoginPage()
   {
       private readonly By toastLocator = By.ClassName("react-toast-notifications__toast__content");

       ...

       public void WhenIClickOnLoginButton()
       {
           ...
           wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(toastLocator, "Login Successful"));
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add waits to all of your methods. Ideally you are adding helper methods to a base class and then using them throughout your code. Examples would be `Click()`, `Type()` or `SendKeys()`, etc. that contain waits and take care of everything for you. Then you just call `Click(loginButtonLocator)`, etc. in your methods.
3. I wouldn't create a method `Toast()` where all it does it return `.Text`. That's easy and common enough to just take of as needed. BUT... if you're going to keep it, add a wait for visible and you don't need to pass in the element if the locator is consistent for all toast messages, and it usually is.

   ```
    public string GetToastMessage()
    {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(toastLocator)).Text;
    }
   ```

   where `toastLocator` is defined at the top of the page class.
4. Name methods to better indicate what that method is doing. Instead of `Toast()` which doesn't indicate what the method is doing, change it to `GetToastMessage()`. Now it's clear what the method does.
5. You could go the extra step and document each method using [XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/). This builds your own documentation that anyone will see when hovering a method, class, etc. It's simple to do and will help you and other developers better understand what a method does and how to use it properly. An example,

   ```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the message in the current toast.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The toast message.</returns>
    public string GetToastMessage()
    {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(toastLocator)).Text;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion you can try with an additional step. I see you are automating a React page and you don't make use of any try-catch blocks in your method, so I made it really simple:

1. Wait for the element to appear on the page with the use of a WebDriverWait

This ensures the element is present on the page and to prevent any Exceptions, because `driver.FindElement` will throw an Exception if the element is not present.

2. Loop until you find the Text `Login succesful`

I find the Stopwatch a nice functionality to use in combination with appearing/disappearing elements. You are iterating through the InnerText value every 200ms and you will either (1) break if the text is visible or (2) if the timer has reached 60 sec.

```
        [When(@"I click on Login Button")]
        public void WhenIClickOnLoginButton()
        {
            // Login button
            loginpage.ClickLoginButton();

            // 1: Initially wait for the WebElement to appear to prevent Exceptions
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("react-toast-notifications__toast__content")));

            // 2: Loop until you find the Login Successful string
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            while (true)
            {
                IWebElement LoginToast = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-toast-notifications__toast__content"));
                if (Toast(LoginToast).Equals("Login Successful"))
                    break;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 60 * 1000)
                    break;
            }
        }
```